# How do you inject named field parameters in Kotlin with Dagger 2?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I have a named parameter in Java that I inject in the following way:

```
@Inject @Named("io")
Scheduler ioScheduler;
```

How do I do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following is the form for Dagger2 & Kotlin for named fields.

```
 @field:[Inject Named("io")]
 lateinit var ioScheduler: Scheduler
```

**see also:**

- [Late initialized properties](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties)
- [Kotlin annotation syntax](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotations)
- [Annotation use-site targets](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)